# principal ideal definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals

Definition: Let $R$ be a ring, $a\in R$. The principal ideal $M=\langle a \rangle$ consists of all elements of the form $ra+as+na+\sum_{i=1}^{m} r_ias_i$

I know that a left principal ideal $M=Ra=\{ra:r\in R\}$

I know that a right principal ideal $M=aR=\{ar:r\in R\}$

I know that a two-sided principal ideal $M=RaR=\{r_ias_i:r_i,s_i\in R\}$

Intuitively I see why "$ra$" and "$as$" and "$\sum_{i=1}^{m} r_ias_i$" are in the set defined above, but why did Hungerford include "$na$"?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: $a+a$, $a+a+a$, $a+a+a+a$, etc. are also in the principal ideal, and not included in $\sum\limits_{i=\color{red}1}^m r_ias_i$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you for your response! But I don't see how the definition can fail if we remove the term $na$ from it. In other words, can you give me a principal ideal $M$ such that unless $na$ is included in the set defined above, $M\not=$ the set defined above?

Comment: So to respond to your comment, is there a case where $ra$ can't do the job $na$ can?

Comment: I'm not sure, but shouldn't you also have $r^na$ and $as^n$?

Comment: I just re-wrote Hungerford's definition.